# Weird behaviour with serial upvoting reversal

Tags: support, reputation, serial-voting, reputation-history

Okay, so I was a *victim* of serial upvoting yesterday. Someone just decided to upvote me 7 times in a very short space of time.

Earlier today, as expected, I seen that I had -70 for Serial Upvoting Reversal.

Now, for some reason, that seems to have changed. It's now taken -34 from me, dropped my yesterday's contribution to 197 (I'd hit the rep cap, was on 215).

My question is, why this change? Surely the -70 was correct and yesterday left unaffected. It seems like a fairly random thing, -34. I realise that I'm actually **better off by 18 (yesterday was 215, now 197, today is -34)**

See here:

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Serial upvoting reversal adjusts for the rep cap; the cap is re-calculated and only the fraction of the votes that would have left you below the cap is reversed. With the serial votes, you reached 200 points for all the up- and down votes, without those serial upvotes, you reached 163 points instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry, not quite sure I follow. If it adjusts for the rep cap, shouldn't I have just been left with 160?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looking at your [per post reputation breakdown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1039608/mattytommo?tab=reputation&sort=post) yesterday you received:

- 23 answer upvotes at +10 each.
- 2 answer downvotes at -2 each.
- 1 accept at +15.
- At a guess, you downvoted other answers 3 times at -1 each.

2 of those upvotes didn't give you any reputation at all as they were cast after you hit the cap. 1 of those upvotes only gave you +7 points; we cannot see how many downvotes you cast before that point but my guess is that you cast 3 downvotes on answers, so you gained back the -4 for the downvotes against you plus another 3 points for downvotes you cast, giving you 7 points from that one vote.

In total, with the cap in place, you gained 215 points yesterday.

However, 7 upvotes, cast early in the day, were serial votes, and were removed again by the script. After these were removed, your cap is recalculated. Now you got:

- 16 answer upvotes at +10 each.
- 2 answer downvotes at -2 each.
- 1 accept at +15.
- At a guess, you downvoted other answers 3 times at -1 each.

Now you don't hit the cap, and there is no compensating +7 points from an upvote somewhere. Without the serial votes you gained 160 - 7 + 15 = 168 points

As a result, the serial vote reversal cost you 215 - 168 = 37 points.

Comment: Good breakdown! One thing though, I downvoted 3 answers, but 2 were deleted (you can see the question at the bottom of my screenshot). It's here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055870/selected-hover-no-background/16056216#16056216  so shouldn't I have gotten 199 for yesterday?

Comment: Perhaps, it's hard to determine for me as I cannot see your downvotes nor what has been deleted since.

Comment: Can you see 3 of those answers were deleted? Well I downvoted the two I didn't edit.

Comment: I can see the deleted posts, I just cannot see who posted on those.